# show only limited categories with a MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I have a mysql database in which there is about hundreds of category for photo album. When i display the album using

```
"SELECT * FROM 'album' `status`='1' ORDER BY `cat_name` DESC LIMIT 10"
```

so it will display the last 10 categories but if i want to display only 15 categories in between from that hundreds of category what the query should be? i have try this.

```
"SELECT * FROM 'album' `status`='1' and `cat_id`='2' || `cat_id`='7' || `cat_id`='8' || `cat_id`='14' || `cat_id`='20' ORDER BY `cat_name` DESC LIMIT 10"
```

here its displaying that category which i want to display but it displaying that inactivate category also which i do not show here by using `status`='1'    (inactive status=0)
can any body help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the `WHERE` keyword before your conditions.

Also, instead of all of those `OR`s or `||`s, use `IN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM album
WHERE status = 1 AND cat_id IN (2,7,8,14,20)
ORDER BY cat_name DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for solution zane its get worked. both your and holger solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parenthesis () around your 'cat_id' or conditions.  The `'status'='1'` AND  is only applying to `'cat_id'=2'` but not the other 'cat_id' since conditions are read from left to right.

```
"SELECT * FROM 'album' WHERE `status`='1' and (`cat_id`='2' || `cat_id`='7' || `cat_id`='8' || `cat_id`='14' || `cat_id`='20') ORDER BY `cat_name` DESC LIMIT 10"
```